# Cached iTunes Cover Art

Tags: cocoa, applescript, itunes, scripting-bridge

I need to fetch cached cover art from iTunes. Currently I'm working with the scripting bridge, but it only fetches covers that are embedded in the tracks. I've also tried this method here

[Fetch iTunes album artwork without iTunes running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433035/fetch-itunes-album-artwork-without-itunes-running)

but it seems to be broken (at least in iTunes 9.2). Any hints how to solve this?

Regards,
Erik

**Update**

---

```
NSArray *artworks = [[track artworks] get];
for (CMTunesBridgeArtwork *art in artworks) {
    ref.image = [art data];
    break;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, fetching album artwork through scripting iTunes will return artwork both for tracks with embedded artwork and those downloaded from the iTunes store. Can you post some of your scripting bridge code?

Comment: See update above; yes the for seems a little weird (there's some irrelevant other stuff in there that i removed). But as i said, the [track artworks] array only contains covers for tracks that have embedded artwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work around this issue i solved it as follows:

If a track doesn't provide artwork, I search the other album tracks for any artwork. In most cases at least one track has a cover applied. Weird but works.

As a third option I'll parse the cover cache (.itc) files and use artwork from there, but it turned out in almost all cases these cache files are useless, so i only use the first method now.

Regards,
Erik